# LT3045 LDO regulator start-up problem

Tags: ldo

I was using a voltage regulator based on LT3045, everything worked fine but after powering the device after longer time of not using it, it stopped working.

The output voltage that i'm getting after powering the device is -0.6V. It should be +15V.

I think that it's a problem with regulator start-up. I've noticed by accident, that when I short input voltage (+18V) with SET pin for a short moment the regulator starts working and everything is fine until i turn the device off. After turning the device off and powering it up the problem occurs again.

SET pin is a voltage reference pin, it drives a resistor with 100mA current and uses a tantalum capacitor, to keep the reference voltage stable. After powering the device SET pin is at -0.6V. The same as regulator output. When SET pin gets +18V for a while regulator starts working normally and SET pin becomes +15V.

I'm wondering if it's a problem with faulty capacitor or a regulator. It's hard to test it, because the device is fully SMD soldered, regulator is soldered to a thermal pad and replacing the components is a real challenge.

Any ideas?

[image: circuit]

Comment: According to the datasheet: `do not drive SET more than 0.3V below GND during a normal operation or during a fault condition`. If it shows -0.6V, it's *possible* that it is a faulty chip. Couldn't say for sure, though.

Comment: the most suprising thing is that chip worked before...

Comment: You have the current limit pin 6 tied to ground.  According to the datasheet, pg. 12, it states:  "The programming scale factor is nominally 150mA • kΩ."  With 0 kΩ, your limit current is 0.

Comment: As i said - the regulator worked before and application is ok. My current limit is not 0 - in datasheet it is said, that when you don't need a current limiting function you tie ILIM pin to gnd.

Comment: @cubix I didn't say it shouldn't have, or implied it didn't work, just that, somewhere on the road, there is a possibility it simply gave up, because of the reading on the SET pin is below the datasheet recommendation (warning, actually), that's all.

Comment: Where is the negative voltage coming from? I don't see a negative supply in the schematic, is there one elsewhere on the board?  If there is it might be a clue as to what's wrong.  If  there isn't then you have to figure out how you are measuring -0.6V on a board without a negative supply.

Comment: Yes, there is a -15V negative supply on board.

Comment: It could be a sequencing issue.  Have you tried disabling the -15V supply to see if that allows the +15V supply to work?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Disabling the negative supply made the positive work. 

Sequencing issue... what now?

Comment: You can either slow down the -15V startup or speed up the +15V startup.  The +15V speed depends on the Creg cap value.  No info on the -15V supply so can't comment on that.

Comment: Can you use the PG signal on your 15V regulator to enable the -15V rail?

Comment: My -15V regulator is LT3090. No PG signal I guess.

Comment: Ok, from 3090 datasheet:

"Moreover, since the SHDN pin is bidirectional, it can be
taken beyond ±1.4V to turn-ON the LT3090. In bipolar
supply applications, the positive SHDN threshold can be
used to sequence the turn-ON of LT3090 after the positive
regulator has turned on."

I didn't know before that power supply sequencing may be an issue :(

Comment: Use the PG signal from the +15V regulator to enable the LT3090 via the SHDN! input.  You probably need a pull-up on the PG pin and check all the voltage levels to be sure they're OK

Comment: Thank you very much. Is sequencing in bipolar supply using LDO regulators always necessary?

Comment: It's often necessary, maybe not always.

Answer (score 1):

Something downstream drives the negative voltage. Install a Schottky diode between your Vcc and GND to prevent Vcc being pulled lower than -300 mV.